# Gurobi Python sensitivity analysis log file

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, pulp

I'm solving a linear program with Gurobi / PuLP and I would like to access to additional logs from the solver - at least know which constraints are constraining the most the solution, or which one are making my problem infeasible when it is the case.

Is there a way to retrieve this kind of information and to store it in a log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are the values of the dual (pi) variables for the constraints.

To obtain these you need to do something like this after you have solved the problem.

```
[c_name, c.pi for (c_name, c) in prob.constraints.items()]
```

Stu